# How to check mobile network state?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I'd like to be able to identify an unactivated/disconnected SIM card, i.e,

> About phone>SIM status>Mobile Network State>"Disconnected"

Here are some of the things I've tried so far.

```
telephonyManager.simState == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY
```

returns true even in the disconnected scenario.

```
telephonyManager.dataState != TelephonyManager.DATA_DISCONNECTED
```

returns false even when mobile data is turned off in an active device.

Can any of the network capabilities (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities#constants_1) used for this? Some indicate the connection between the carrier, but I'm unsure which one applies to this scenario.